# Amazon DynamoDB client is so slow

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I just tried dynamodb example from amazon.

I understand the advantages on the db itself, but I found it uses http connection to write and read data.
If I have 1000 writes/sec, does that means I need have 1000 connections available to write? If so, isn't it too heavy for a client server?

Is there any way to connect using TCP as normal db? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not opening a connection per say for each query, you're making a request. Because you're in a very high speed network inside amazon the latency is very low even with http. Sure TCP might be "Faster" but that's just if you're comparing the speed of connection in a non-real world. The real benefit that you get with HTTP is that you can scale it out very very easily. What they've done is added a few ms of latency on each request and in return they've guaranteed that the request will be less than 10ms. In their documentation they state that the response time they guarantee is  single digit ms.

So sure HTTP is slow compared to TCP if you're just comparing the protocol. But when you actually look at the product you'll see its speed is far from slow, its probably one of the fastest databases that you can design when you start bringing large data sets into mind.

Comment: Meaning AWS SDK will maintain a connection pool itself? So should I make a static client object or better init a new one for each request?

Comment: There's no real connection pool for http. Http has what you call persistent connections and keep alive http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection. But in order to get the most performance out of your application you would need to still have multiple connections open at a time. You could create one SimpleDB instance for each thread.

Answer (score 1):

Having the throughput as 1000 writes/sec means that your data is distributed in such a manner to guarantee you of 1000 successful writes to your data in a second.
dynamodb is really fast and reliable in a scalable environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 1000 writes per sec , then you need to configure write throughput for the table as 1000 assuming each data item size is 1KB ,if it is smaller or larger than 1KB ,use round off number after dividing with 1kb for example 1.6kb/1kb =1.6 ~ 2 i.e write throughput has to be 2000 for 1000 writes per sec .Even after http connection, I found it very fast considering the fact our insertion service is also running in same EC2 zone.